# Joint query in Linq to SQL to select all records even there are some null in the columns of foreign keys

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net, linq-to-sql, join

> I'd like to take all suggestion either in C# or VB.NET.

I have a DB diagram like the image below. I also include the database script here @ http://pastebin.com/pDC25Gkm

[image: Database diagram]

In the Students table, CountryId and RoomId column are allowed null. Because some records do not have info about room and country yet.
Also, some students do not have essays.

I'm doing a joint query with all tables. I want to select all students to
project the result like this:

**Wanted query result.**

[image: Wanted query result]

Here's my current query that gives the result like the image below:

```
    Dim db As New DBDataContext

    Dim query = From st In db.Students _
                Join c In db.Countries On c.Id Equals st.Id _
                Join r In db.Rooms On r.Id Equals st.RoomId _
                Join b In db.Buildings On b.Id Equals r.BuildingId _
                Join es In db.Essays On es.StudentId Equals st.Id _
                Select st, c, r, b, es

    'put query result into datatable
    Dim dt = New DataTable("Result")
    dt.Columns.Add("Id", GetType(Integer))
    dt.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Room", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Building", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Country", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Essay", GetType(String))

    For Each q In query

        dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {q.st.Id, q.st.FullName, q.r.RoomNumber, q.b.BuildingName, q.c.CountryName, q.es.Eassay})

    Next

    'bind to list view
    lvStudent.DataSource = dt
    lvStudent.DataBind()
```

**current query result**

[image: Current query result]

I got only one result back because I have (2) William NoMan record in every table. But I don't get anything about others, like (3) Sync Master who has everything but RoomId.

What do I need to modify the query above so it will give me all students like in the wanted query image above? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried searching the web for a linq `LFET JOIN`? Look into the `.DefaultIfEmpty()` method

Answer (score 1):

I used the following query:

```
    Dim query = From st In db.Students _
             From c In db.Countries.Where(Function(c) c.Id = st.CountryId).DefaultIfEmpty _
             From r In db.Rooms.Where(Function(r) r.Id = st.RoomId).DefaultIfEmpty _
             From b In db.Buildings.Where(Function(b) b.Id = r.BuildingId).DefaultIfEmpty _
             From es In db.Essays.Where(Function(es) es.StudentId = st.Id).DefaultIfEmpty _
             Select st.Id, st.FullName, c.CountryName, r.RoomNumber, b.BuildingName, es.Eassay
```

It gives the result I wanted but I'm not sure if it's good query. There must be another way better than this.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can achieve this using sql server query.

```
select students.id, fullname, isnull(roomid,'') as Room, 
isnull((select top 1 buildingid from rooms where rooms.id = roomid), '') as building,
isnull((select top 1 countryname from countries where Countries.id = countryid), '') as Country,
isnull((select top 1 eassay from essays where Essays.studentid = Students.id), '') as essay from students
```