# How to use System.Linq extension method in VB.NET project with Option Strict ON

Tags: vb.net, linq, option-strict

I'm using .NET 3.5 In my DataLayer class I have references of System.Core,System.Data.Linq, System.Data.DataSetExtensions. But 
I cantnot use this feature in Linq query if I have **Option Strict ON**:

```
    Dim query = From st In db.Students _
         From c In db.Countries.Where(Function(c) c.Id = st.CountryId).DefaultIfEmpty _
         From r In db.Rooms.Where(Function(r) r.Id = st.RoomId).DefaultIfEmpty _
         From b In db.Buildings.Where(Function(b) b.Id = r.BuildingId).DefaultIfEmpty _
         From es In db.Essays.Where(Function(es) es.StudentId = st.Id).DefaultIfEmpty _
         Select st.Id, st.FullName, c.CountryName, r.RoomNumber, b.BuildingName, es.Eassay
```

It will yield the following error:

```
Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Where' can be called with these arguments:
    Extension method 'Public Function Where(predicate As System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of System.Func(Of Country, Integer, Boolean))) As System.Linq.IQueryable(Of Country)'

defined in 'System.Linq.Queryable': Nested function does not have the same signature as delegate 'System.Func(Of Country, Integer, Boolean)'.

Extension method 'Public Function Where(predicate As System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of System.Func(Of Country, Boolean))) As System.Linq.IQueryable(Of Country)' defined in 'System.Linq.Queryable': Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Boolean?' to 'Boolean'.
    Extension method 'Public Function Where(predicate As System.Func(Of Country, Integer, Boolean)) As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of Country)' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable': Nested function does not have the same signature as delegate 'System.Func(Of Country, Integer, Boolean)'.
    Extension method 'Public Function Where(predicate As System.Func(Of Country, Boolean)) As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of Country)' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable': Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Boolean?' to 'Boolean'..........
```

The "Where" clause is Member of System.Linq.Queryable

> Public Shared Function Where(Of TSource)(ByVal source As System.Linq.IQueryable(Of TSource), ByVal predicate As System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of System.Func(Of TSource, Boolean))) As System.Linq.IQueryable(Of TSource)

And "DefaultIfEmpty" is Member of System.Linq.Queryable

> Public Shared Function DefaultIfEmpty(Of TSource)(ByVal source As System.Linq.IQueryable(Of TSource)) As System.Linq.IQueryable(Of TSource)

If I set **Option Strict OFF**, **there's no problem**.

How to use these System.Linq extension methods in VB.NET project with Option Strict ON ? Thank you

Comment: If you get really bored of using Strict, try Option Infer On to enable type inference. Just an idea, if it breaks rules/patterns then ignore this :) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384665.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like CountryId is a nullable value type, hence

```
c.CountryId = st.CountryId
```

will be a nullable boolean instead of a regular boolean.

Try something like this

```
From st In db.Students _
From c In db.Countries.Where(Function(c) If(c.CountryId = st.CountryId, False)) _
Select st.FirstName, c.CountryName
```

BTW, it's seems your looking for a *group* join anyhow:

```
From s In db.Students
Group Join c In db.Countries On s.CountryID Equals c.CountryID Into Group
From g In Group.DefaultIfEmpty
Select New With {.Name = s.Name, .CountryName = If(g IsNot Nothing, g.CountryName, "")}
```

Comment: Please see my update query. I need to modify those query so it works with Option Strict ON. If I used this "Join c in Countries On st.CountryID Equals c.CountryID" I get only those records that have CountryId. But I want to get all students that's why I came to use db.Countries.Where(Function(c) c.Id = st.CountryId).DefaultIfEmpty but it won't work with Option Strick ON. If you'd like to see DB structure, please go here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870964

Comment: Thanks for the DB structure, that makes things clearer. As I said, your problem is that CountryID in Students is nullable. I'll update my answer...

Comment: If there's any option to the query and produce the same result I'd like to try it as well. Thanks.

Comment: you could just alter your where-clause to use 'If(c.CountryId = st.CountryId, False)' instead of 'c.CountryId = st.CountryId', since the former one yields False to the where-clause if st.CountryId is nothing.

Comment: I tried your First Suggestion but it worked only if select Students, Countries, and Rooms. When I added another line to select Essays table like this  From es In db.Essays.Where(Function(es) If(es.StudentId = st.Id, False)).DefaultIfEmpty _ it's throw same error. Is there's any reason why it's like this?

Comment: Your second suggestion is superb. Thank you very much. :D